# ios 7.0 login to twitter in ios simulator issues

Tags: iphone, twitter, ios7, ios-simulator

i develop an iOS app that used Tweet Sheet to post a tweet. I use a iOS 7.0 simulator, then I input my Twitter account on setting. But, when I try login, I got an alert message.

[image: alert message]
[image: unavailable mark]

I guess, its because of UNAVAILABLE mark on side of twitter logo. Im sure, this is not because I wrong to input my account. Then, I try to built my apps in 6.1 simulator, and its works.
Thanks for help.

Comment: I also recommend using the simulators keyboard to enter your Twitter user name and password instead of using your computers keyboard.  command+shift+k shows / hides keyboard.

I was getting this same problem, and it showed my twitter handle, but when I clicked it there was a popup saying the username or password was incorrect.  I re-entered my creds by clicking on the simulators keyboard and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working fine for me on both simulator of 6.1 and 7.0.

Try to reset your simulator content and settings and set the Id and Password again and check it.

Hope it works fine for you.

Comment: its no use in xcode 5.0, twitter setting always say unavailable, same as the others like facebook, flickr, and vimeo.

Comment: Yes but if you want to share only then just type your user id and password there so that you can share from your app. I just did that and it accepts my credentials.

Comment: @evanhutomo: Is your problem solved or not?

Comment: isn't yet. I confused, If I create new project, its always pointing on ios 7.0 simulator. There no choice to select 6.1.

Comment: It is because your deployment target is set to 7.0. Change it to 6.1 then it will show you both the simulator 6.1 and 7.0.

Comment: Please upvote for it if its useful to you.